# Django ModelForm is_valid saves the instance automatically

Tags: django, modelform

I found the ModelForm in Django is very easy to use and it saves great time of development.

However, I was stuck when I realize the is_valid actually saves the ModelForm! I would like to know if this is expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

What happens to me is

```
    form=SOME_MODEL_FORM(...., instance=cafe)
    print cafe.name # "CAFE OLD NAME"
    if request.method="POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            ### HERE the cafe instance has been changed
            print cafe.name # "CAFE NEW NAME"
```

I use post_save to debug, the is_valid did save the model!

My current workaround is to save the model in another object before calling is_valid, then save back to override the chang. It is really hacking and I would like to have an more elegant way to achieve the same goal (not save the model after is_valid call).

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No `form.is_valid()` does not save the new data in DB. However, it updates the instance object with new attributes so that it can use them when you call `form.save()`.

Here is how you can verify this:

```
>>> mc = MyModel.objects.get(id=3)
>>> mf=MyModelForm({'name': 'abcd'}, instance=mc)
>>> mc.name
u'oldName'
>>> mf.is_valid()
True
>>> mc.name
u'abcd'
>>> mc2 = MyModel.objects.get(id=3)  #get the new instance from DB
>>> mc2.name
u'OldName'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan,yes,the call to is_valid actually updates the existing model, but is there any way to avoid this default behavior? I would like to perform a sanity check before updating the model.

Comment: @zhaocong, sanity checks can be done in form or models `clean()` method.

Comment: Alright, this is new for me. Thanks Rohan for this. I need some more info . Rohan, I am looking into the source code here cant find where exactly is this thing done, Can you show me (line number and file in django source code)?

Answer (score 2):

form.is_valid() doesnt save the form, it just checks validation  as the name implies.

see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid

Read here for is_valid method in a modelform
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-is-valid-method-and-errors

Comment: unfortunately that's not true, @Rohan got the point and that's exactly what I want to discuss about.